# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on Android mobile connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, android

So, I've got an issue that's been a real headscratcher for me for a while, and after going around in circles with it for a few days, I figured I'd see if anyone else could help me out.

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS webserver running Nginx and php5-fpm. On top of that, I'm running a couple of Wordpress blogs, nothing fancy there, just vanilla installs.  Upon trying to connect to these sites, (using both the www and bare TLD version of the URLs), I run in to the following:

1. Works perfectly when connected to WiFi/hardwired internet, regardless of the device used to connect.
2. Works perfectly when connecting via 4G on an iPhone 6.
3. Throws ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when connecting via 4G on Samsung Android phones... I've tried a Note 5 and an Galaxy 7 Edge -- looking for a few more devices to try with. I suspect the issue probably extends to all Android mobiles.

I was leaning towards an Nginx configuration issue, but I maintain another WP site, (on a different but identically configured server), that has no trouble loading up via my mobile connection, so I'm a bit lost.

When I look at the Nginx logs on the server in question, I'm oddly not seeing anything logged at all, despite reloading and getting the ERR_CONNECTION_RESET mutiple times.

I know it's not a lot to go on, but any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the iPhone and the Android using the same 4G carrier? I suspect, it yould be a carrier issue.

Comment: Maybe a tcp windowing issue?  If you connect the phone's wifi to the network the server is on, does the problem happen?  (you'd want to try by IP address locally rather than use a URL unless everything is getting a pubilc IP)

Comment: I was wondering about the carrier too, but yeah, they're both AT&T. Also, as I said before, I have another server that is almost identically configured, and the Android phones appear to be connecting to that just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Open playstore , search for the google chrome page
And click uninstall
Tgis will remove any updates installed on google chrome . And wilk gey it back to work

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue. In my case the cause was data saver settings in chrome.
Go to chrome settings, select data saver and disable it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have site redirection on your page (HTTP 302).
I have similar problem when using Chrome for Android with Data Saver feature turned on. Problem gone by turning off Data Saver or go to Incognito mode. I know this is not ideal situation as we can't really tell users to turn off their Data Saver.
My temporary solution is using META-REFRESH to redirect rather than sending 302 header.

Cheers!
JP